# App show "Your device isn't compatible with this version" on Play store but manually apk installed working

Tags: android, android-manifest

I create my android app and released on Google Play. I can install APK to my device or any other device, it working fine.

But through the Google Play store it shows "Your device isn't compatible with this version" in my device and other.

I can't figure out how to get any information on why the play store thinks it's not compatible.

I also clear my play store cache and also clear data but nothing happen.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/logo"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">

    <activity
        android:name=".Test.OTGTest"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".Test.ColorTest"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

    <activity
        android:name=".Test.ChargerTest"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

    <activity
        android:name=".Test.TouchTest"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

    <activity
        android:name=".Test.WifiTest"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

    <activity
        android:name=".Activity.SplashActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".Activity.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

</application>
```

Please help me and provide some solution...

Comment: Show gradle file for `minSdkVersion` and check if it should be compatibile with your devices Api

Comment: Check your device SDK and minSDKVersion of the app

Comment: if it is an issue with a minimum version so it cannot install the app manually also.

Comment: If you check on play store to supported devices list you can find only a few devices and normally its lots of.

Comment: @SkypeDogg 
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "*********"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
   
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'

Comment: I have not get any solution to my issue, yet Play store shows "Your device isn't compatible with this version" while same apk file installed manually.. Plz help

Answer (score 1):

I already face this issue. some permission is not comfortable with your device. so need to remove permission from manifest file and update your app to the play store.

Comment: `USE_FINGERPRINT` is deprecated in Api 28 (Android 9). I don't know if it is the problem but you should use `USE_BIOMETRIC` for Api 28

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />

Remove both permission and update it.

Comment: Its not API deprecated issue.

Comment: @Mehul, I remove both permissions <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />, But result remain same...

Comment: @PriyankSharma Okay, the issue is some permissions are not compatible with your device.

Comment: If it is tested app so try to remove all permissions and update to the play store. This is only for the test purpose.

Comment: I have no answer for this.

Comment: This issue is not only my device, other devices shows same things

Comment: Yes, I know. I have faced the same issue. If you check on play store to supported devices list you can find only a few devices and normally its lots of.

Comment: Remove all permissions and update to the play store. This is only for the test purpose.

Comment: I have removed all permission and generate signed apk. Then I tried to install apk manually first but it shows "play protect doesn't recognise this app's developer. Apps from unknown developers can sometimes be unsafe" issue and not installed.

Comment: That is some security. You can try with adb install -r released_app.apk

Comment: Update your app on play store and wait for the updating app.

Comment: Okay, Wait for play store review.

Comment: Did anyone got the solution, I'm also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check your device SDK and minSDKVersion of the app

Comment: Thank U but there is no issue in device SDK and minSDKVersion of the app

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue and found that the only cause was some of the permissions. I was to use those features so don't have to remove the permissions but what solved my issue was putting `android:required="false"` so those devices having no `fingerPrint` or other sensors can also use my app.

**Example:**

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
```

Above if any device has no camera then my app will be able to install on it too. This makes Google Play Store to let people install your app on devices don't having some of the sensors/features you mentioned in `manifest` file.

Comment: android:required="false" is not available in uses-permission, it shows in 'uses-features'

Comment: Your are using permission for camera so you have to also use feature tag for camera and same goes for finger print and others.

Comment: Have you tried the feature tag (with required=false) for all other permissions as well?

Comment: Which mobile device are you using and its android version?

Comment: Brand- Samsung version- 9.0 (Pie). But this issue in most of devices not only my.